# How to wrap a non-object-safe Trait in an object-safe one?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, dynamic-dispatch

I originally encountered this issue when attempting to create a Rayon ParallelIterator that a `flat_map` operation was applied to a dynamic number of times [see this post on the Rayon issue tracker](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/628#issuecomment-545091260).

*Note: I asked the same question on the Rust User forum as well ([see here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-wrap-a-non-object-safe-trait-in-an-object-safe-one/33904)), but StackOverflow might be a better venue for this question.*

For standard (i.e. that execute serially) `Iterator`s the following works:

```
fn fancy<Input, Output, Item>(input: Input, depth: usize) -> Output
where
    Input : IntoIterator<Item = Item>,
    Output : std::iter::FromIterator<Item>,
    Item : Copy + std::ops::Add<Output = Item>,
{
    let mut iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Item>> = Box::new(input.into_iter());
    for _ in 0..depth {
        iter = Box::new(iter.flat_map(|x| vec![x, x + x].into_iter()));
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

When working with Rayon's `ParallelIterator`s, however, things get iffy: `ParallelIterator` requires types that implement it to be `Sized`, making them non-object safe and thus impossible to pass around as trait object. Thus the following straight translation does not work:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
fn fancy2<Input, Output, Item>(input: Input, depth: usize) -> Output
where
    Input : IntoParallelIterator<Item = Item>,
    Output : FromParallelIterator<Item>,
    Item : Copy + std::ops::Add<Output = Item> + Send,
{
    let mut iter: Box<dyn rayon::iter::ParallelIterator<Item = Item>> = Box::new(input.into_par_iter());
    for _ in 0..depth {
        iter = Box::new(iter.flat_map(|x| vec![x, x + x].into_par_iter()));
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

---

My question is: How can we wrap a non-object-safe trait like `ParallelIterator` in a new trait that is object-safe, so we can e.g. perform a dynamic operation on it like in above example?

Comment: Have you seen [this comment](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/628#issuecomment-456921893) by Niko? If so, is there anything unclear about it?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Most definitely; see my response two replies down in that thread. I was unable to get the  proposed wrapping to work; possibly because I do not understand well enough how to set it up.